# Jquery onselect onchange radio button value

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

So based on this example: http://jsfiddle.net/RhnvU/ I am trying to pass the value of a radio button into an area that is essentially inside a modal box. But here's the thing, I am using a function to display the results of a drop down box as well.

When I use this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $('#rental input').on('change', function() {
       alert($('input[name=radioName]:checked', '#rental').val()); 
    });
});
</script>
```

and then place this code anywhere but inside the div, it works fine:

```
echo ' <input type="radio" name="radioName" value="' . $rest . '" />' . $format_number . '<br>';
```

But as soon as I try to drop it into this div:

```
<div id="txtHint"></div>
```

which is what returns the results from a php script into that div (id="txtHint") it does not  work. I've tried to modify the $('#rental input to match the txtHint div id tag, but that doesn't seem to work. So what is it that I am doing wrong?

Thanks

**EDIT**

Here's the code to call to the api and return the data back into the txtHint div

```
   function showUser(str){
     if (str==""){
           document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
           return;
     } 
     if (window.XMLHttpRequest){// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
          xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
     }
     else{ // code for IE6, IE5
         xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
     xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
       if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
           document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
      }
        xmlhttp.open("GET","api/api-test.php?q="+str,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
```

Comment: Show us what doesn't work, instead of what what works. I dont understand what the problem is in that fiddle

Comment: You seem to have glossed over the php script/ajax part... how is that involved? If you're trying to attach jQuery events to DOM elements loaded via ajax, document.ready won't do that for you. You either need to delegate the events or attach them when the ajax call is done

Comment: what is  your question??

Comment: I'm trying to make it so that when the ajax results are called back into id="txtHint", and a radio button is selected, it will alert the value that has been selected. I'm pretty certain it's a modification of this line: $('#rental input').on('change', function() {

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your comments, you're trying to attach events to HTML injected via ajax response.

The initial document.ready code won't work because those elements don't actually exist yet. There are two ways to resolve this:

You can attach the event after injecting the ajax response:

```
$.get(url, function(resp){
  // insert the new div
  $('#rental input').change( // ...code here
});
```

Or you can use delegation to listen to current and new events:

```
$('#rental').on('change', 'input', function() {
```

(Assuming `id="rental"` is already on the page. The point is to attach the delegated event to a container that is constant, it's always on the page. Some people just use `body` for heavy ajax pages)

Comment: That's exactly what I needed. For clarifications, your delegation example is what worked. Now, instead of using the alert, I need to get that result into a div to show.